# iOS Key-Value programming: to-many accsessors implementation improves performance?

Tags: ios, performance, key-value, key-value-coding

Reading the Apple's documentations about key-value programming, I often come across statements:

> If benchmarking indicates that performance improvements are required,
>   you can also implement `<some kind of accessor>`
>
> Performance can be increased in the case of mutable to-many relationships, often significantly.

([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html))

can somebody explain how the Collection Accessors can help improve performance?